# Function to store data.frames and calculate mean?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, mean

I'm trying to come up with a function and got stuck. I need to run a function (ses.mpd) 1000 times with randomized matrices. The outputs (data.frames) should be stored and then a data.frame with means of those 1000 output data.frames should be calculated.

Example:

output data.frames

```
        ntaxa  mpd.obs  mpd.rand.mean  mpd.rand.sd
sample1   3       10         9               0.2
sample2   6       15         12              0.6
sample3   4       9          10              0.1


        ntaxa  mpd.obs  mpd.rand.mean  mpd.rand.sd
sample1   6       12         10              0.5
sample2   4       12         15              0.3
sample3   7       4          7               0.3
```

result data.frame should look like this

```
       ntaxa  mpd.obs  mpd.rand.mean  mpd.rand.sd
sample1   4.5     11         9.5            0.35
sample2   5       13.5       13.5           0.45
sample3   5.5     6.5        8.5            0.2
```

I think I have save the 1000 data.frames in a list and then maybe use the ddply function in plyr, but I have not really an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the matrices are the same (e.g. same dimensions and same variable locations), then I would store them in a 3d array and use `apply` or `rowMeans`, etc.  The latter will be faster.

Using a built-in dataset:

```
> dim(UCBAdmissions)
[1] 2 2 6
> rowMeans( UCBAdmissions, dims=c(2)  )
          Gender
Admit          Male    Female
  Admitted 199.6667  92.83333
  Rejected 248.8333 213.00000
```